# AutoML VISION Google SingleLabel Classification output TopK results

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision, google-cloud-automl, automl

Currently **AutoML Vision API** is outputting a SingleLabel with the respective **Score**

For example:

I trained the model with 3 classes:

1. A
2. B
3. C

Then when I am using **Test & Use** and I am uploading another image, I got only
[CURRENT OUTPUT]

1. `Class A and 0.988437 / 0.99`

Is there a way I can get this type of output with Top_K classes ( for example Top 3 (k=3) )
[DESIRED OUTPUT]

1. `Class A and 0.988437 / 0.99`
2. `Class C and 0.3551 / 0.36`
3. `Class B  and 0.1201 / 0.12`

Sorted based on their Score.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Single-label classification assigns a single label to each classified image and it returns only one predicted class.

Multi-label is more suited for your use case as it allows an image to be assigned multiple labels.

In the UI (which is what you seem to be using) you can specify the type of classification you want your custom model to perform when you [create your dataset](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/create-datasets#create-dataset).

[image]

If, for any reason, you would like to have the option to get all/k predicted classes scores on the single-label classification, I suggest that you raise a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1161131).

Comment: I solved this working with their API and the JSON they provide. But it would be great if they could add this functionality. Also, how are they performing the AutoML training? Are there all the technical detail available somewhere? I saw the NAS on GitHub but nothing else

Comment: If you are reffering to automl/NASLib, this is not an official Google repo. And AFAIK the technical details are not available. AutoML is all about giving ML power to people that haven't such expertise.

Comment: Regarding your solution, could you share it or share the documentation you followed because when I tried the API, the predicted class was also one (for single-label classification per image). This would help any future user having the same issue.